# How to move a file if the folder name contains the filename

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I am very new to shell scripting in linux.

I have a bunch of files in source `directory`. I have to move the files to the target `directory` where the folder should contains the file name(not exact match).

Ex:
**My source directory**

```
/var/backup/
logstash-avi-core.spec
logstash-core.spec
ftpcore.spec
```

**My destination directory**

```
/path
/logstash-avi-core-2.2.0
/logstash-core-2.1.1
/ftpcore.spec-2.0
```

I have written a script based on the reference but my script is not working. The files are not get copied to the target directory

```
for path in /var/backup/${1}
do
    if [ -f "${path}" ]
    then
        filename="$(<<< "${file}" awk -F'.')"
        if [ -n "${filename}" ]
        then
            cp "${path}" "/path/${1}/"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Thanks in advance

**Update as per the clarification in the comments:**
I have mentioned the target directory `"/path/${1}/"` in cp "${path}" "/path/${1}/".
I want to read the filename from the source directory and I have to search the foldername containing filename and need to move the file to the matched folder. This is my requirement.

**Update2**
I have modified filenames and directory names.

Comment: How can the script know the target directory? Can we simply take the first letters until the first non-letter character and look for a directory name starting with that? What if you have a directory called `foo_1` and another called `foo_2`? Where should the file `foo` go to? Please [edit] your question and clarify your requirements. Also, the script you show has syntax errors, please always include the errors you get in your question.

Comment: @terdon. Please find the response for your questions. 1. I have mentioned the target directory in `cp`. 2. My directory name is unique it wont be foo_1 and foo_2. 3. i couldn't find the syntax error while I am running it doesn't show any errors. Since I am newbiw to scripting I couldn't figure. Can you please provide your guidance to alter my script

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning. That said, where have you mentioned the target directory? You only mention `$1` and don't explain where that takes its values from. The syntax error is the space after `filename=`. You need to show us the _exact_ script you are using.

Comment: @terdon Question was edited with additional information. The above script is the one which I am using it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to take the first characters of each file name until the first non-letter, and match them against the first characters of the target directory until the first `_`. Assuming that each such pattern only matches once, you can do:

```
for file in /var/backup/*; do 
    fname=${file##*/}; 
    fname=${fname/.*/}; 
    cp -v "$file" /path/"$fname"*/; 
done
```

The result is:

```
$ ls /path/*
/path/adbs_32:
adbs.spec

/path/dmsx_ty_32:
dmsx.spec

/path/fomru_ts_td-45:
fomru32.spec

/path/gend_monitor:
gend.spec
```

Comment: My comparison didn't depend on the non letter. For example my file name is `rty-ion.spec` my target folder name `rty-ion-2.2.2`. Then my file `rty-ion.spec` should move to the folder `rty-ion-2.2.2`. My filename should compare with folder name omitting the numeric part in the folder.

Comment: It worked like awesome. Thank you man. You saved my day.

Comment: But some of the file got omitted. For eg: my filename `logstash-core-avi.spec`. Didnt move to the folder `logstash-core-avi-2.1.3`. How can I handle this.

Comment: @Mangoski then edit your question and explain that. You have a file called  `fomru32.spec` and a directory called `/fomru_ts_td-45`. That's why I assumed that you wanted only the alphabetical part of the file name.

Comment: Question updated with filenames and foldernames

Comment: @Mangoski, OK, but you need to explain how we can know what file corresponds to what directory. Do we just remove the numbers from the directory names?

Comment: yes you are correct by removing the numbers from the directory will give the filename

Comment: @Mangoski OK, see updated answer.